# What libraries/code to I need to use a MyoWare muscle sensor with a Raspberry pi?

Tags: sensor, i2c, pi-zero, spi, c++

My robotics class is trying to take signals from a [MyoWare Muscle Sensor](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2699) and feed them to a Raspberry Pi Zero. For ADC, we are using a [MCP3008](https://www.adafruit.com/product/856) chip.

Because most people use Arduinos for these sensors, we can't find any example code or libraries. Does anyone know of a place where we can start, code-wise? We are trying to use c++.

Comment: You will need to write code to get the values from the HAT.  I don't see how we can help given the lack of provided detail.

Comment: @joan What details do you need me to provide? I don't know if there are any libraries for this, so I'm just asking where to start. I don't have any code yet.

Comment: It's implicit here that either anyone who could possibly give you any help must already know what a "MyoWare Muscle Sensor" is, or that you figure it is easy enough for others to spend time researching it themselves because they are so eager to be of service ;)  Most likely, neither of these things is true, so it might behoove you to explain a little more about what the device outputs and how it is attached to the pi (you mention an ADC, but...).

Comment: @goldilocks I have added all of the information I have to the question. I have been researching this myself for weeks, and since I haven't been successful, I thought I should ask about it on a website designed for people eager to answer questions and help other people with Raspberry Pis. I appreciate your feedback on my question, and will continue to add more information if I find any more relevant information.

Comment: The reality on technical websites is that there are two groups of people:  Those who answer most of the questions, and those who ask most of the questions.  There is not much overlap, although over time people may migrate from the latter to the former group.  People in the latter group are apt to misunderstand the attitude and perspective of people in the former group ;)  You may find this enlightening: https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/795/5538 ...or not.  Good luck!

Comment: The links might have been sufficient had one of them not been a 404.

Comment: @goldilocks I fixed the links and clarified the question.

Comment: https://learn.adafruit.com/reading-a-analog-in-and-controlling-audio-volume-with-the-raspberry-pi

Comment: @Janka Thanks. I'll see if I can translate that into c++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/46664/i2c-cannot-get-data/57490#57490) is a minimal example in C how to interface an I²C chip (a DS7505 in that case) without any further libraries. You have to read the [MCP3008 datasheet](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjNzvedp4jZAhVsBMAKHet1DdkQFggxMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcdn-shop.adafruit.com%2Fdatasheets%2FMCP3008.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0CYagnunDkT0I-FQ4vstht), then tweak that example program as you need it for your chip.

Comment: I just saw the MCP3008 is SPI rather than I²C, so my answer doesn't match. Please remove your tick so I can delete it.

Comment: I think the general point is clear enough.  There is a link to a Raspberry Pi based example on the Adafruit page; it's in python but even if you don't program in it (I don't) python is not hard to read (in addition, parts of the modules will be in C).  Further, the Pi specific C libs (e.g. pigpio) should have examples of SPI usage. Beware there's an MCP3008 example on the pigpio page that uses bit-banging, you probably don't want that, but it may help clarify how the ADC works together with the adafruit stuff *and especially the datasheet.*  They are not super complex.

Comment: @Janka It's fine that its SPI. I will ad that as a tag. I had the question tagged I2C because we had been previously using that for the output of our project.